# Should one use lodash functions like _.map and _.forEach once they are part of ecmascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I was just curious if it is of any use, or is that deprecated (assuming we don't want to be IE-compliant.

Comment: They already are part of ES since years. So why do you still use lodash?

Comment: I'm curious why are they are a part of lodash... it's just from the prehistoric times, or are they fixing some fault of the native counterparts?

Comment: Yes, both. Check https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Resources

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If `map()` and `forEach()` are the only reasons you're using lodash, you can probably ditch it today. However, there's a lot of other [goodies](https://lodash.com/docs) that come with lodash, and they ultimately lead to you writing less code. Just look at some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lodash) to get an idea of what lodash can do for you. Many of these utilities will never be part of ECMAScript.

Comment: could you name a few reasons to use _.map instead of built-in map ? (and also forEach?